# How do system DLLs work with incompatible versions of Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

Visual Studio 2015 and 2012 have incompatible C runtime libraries. If I try to link my 2015-built application with a link-library that I've built using 2012 then I will get linker errors.

However, I can link both 2015 and 2012 apps to system libraries such as OpenGL32.dll. How do they achieve that?

Is it simply a matter of statically linking to the CRT (e.g. /MT instead of /MD)? When I try that I still get link errors.

Comment: There are other things to worry about than the threading model. For example, say a `std::string &` is used as a parameter in a library function. Also say the implementation of `std::string` changed between 2012 and 2015 (a very likely possibility), calling the library function with this different `string` can be an adventure. But if the dll interface is nothing but C-style functions using Plain Old Data (POD) data types, it can be called with just about anything, including other languages.

Comment: Basically, other libraries maintain their interfaces, both on source and binary level. Also on Windows you can have multiple C runtimes in your process loaded at the same time, so everyone gets what he wants. Of course those runtimes are not interoperable.

Comment: The Windows System DLL's are not tied to Visual Studio. They're usable even from assembly. Even stronger, they might be used with a language that didn't even exist when the DLLs were written. That is logical: applications need to adapt to the OS, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the errors you are referring to are undefined reference to decorated names as used by c++ the reason it works for other libraries is that they only export a C interface. Even where the system libraries export polymorphic objects (as in COM for example) they do so through a C language interface. And yes, if those other libraries don't complain about undefined references of their own then they have been statically linked to a run-time.

Also MSVC has object file and linker extensions that prevent linking object files that depend on the C++ run-time from being used with a different version of the library. This is done even though the code would work just fine if built from source and then linked against the new run-time. It is very easy for objects to change in incompatible ways if rebuilt from source, sometimes even without any changes to the code.